# Google sheets - display only rows containing a digit in range [1-9]?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have very little knowledge of Google sheets but I need to filter column A (a list of URLs) to display, for example, only URLs containing a digit in the text string. I see there's a filter button but I can't find any online documentation that explains how to do this like it was a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

put this for example in **C1**:

```
=QUERY(A:A; "select A where A matches '.*[0-9]+.*'"; 0)
```

[image]

---

to kill off **zeros** you can try this one:

```
=QUERY(A:A; "select A where A matches '.*[1-9]+.*' and not A matches '.*[0]+.*'"; 0)
```

[image]